# Heter for only doing birkat kohanim on Yom Tov

Tags: halacha, minhag, mitzvah, birchas-kohanim, leniencies

There is a minhag, a predominantly ashkenazc diaspora one, to only do Birkat Kohanim on Yom Tov. My question is what is the Heter for this? There is a general principle we don’t pass up mitzvot when we have the opportunity and they won’t burden us, why would this be any different?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

R Ari Henkin ([here](https://outorah.org/p/78675/)) brings two reasons for the custom you mention

> There are a number of reasons why Ashkenazi congregations in the
> Diaspora only perform Birkat Kohanim on Yom Tov. **The most celebrated
> answer is that a Kohen is only permitted to perform the Birkat Kohanim
> when he is happy.** It is taught that Jews in the Diaspora are never
> truly happy due to the many social, financial, and political pressures
> that are characteristic of life in the Diaspora. So too, no Jew can be
> truly happy living in Exile, far away from his God-given homeland.
> Even on Shabbat most people are distracted by their weekday pursuits
> and worries, and are not fully at peace. On Yom Tov, however, people
> are in a more festive mood, especially during the Mussaf service. As
> such, the custom evolved to only perform Birkat Kohanim on Yom Tov.
> (Rema, OC 128:44)
>
> Another explanation offered for only performing
> Birkat Kohanim on Yom Tov is that it is **preferable, if possible, for
> Birkat Kohanim to be performed by a Kohen who has recently immersed in
> a mikva**. Since most people don’t immerse in a mikva on a daily basis,
> or even Erev Shabbat for that matter, Birkat Kohanim was deferred to
> Yom Tov when more people make an effort to immerse in a mikva before
> Yom Tov. (Sefer Chasidim 1613; Beit Yosef, OC 128)

See also [here](https://seforimblog.com/2016/06/daily-birkat-cohanim-in-diaspora/) for other reasons.